# Properly filter an observable of an array of objects by whether a particular property on each index is true?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

So I have an Observable of type Student[]. That is to say an observable of an array of objects. Student has a property `id: number` .How do I filter out indices of the student array based on a property. For example lets say students$ is an observable of type Observable[Student] and I'd like to remove a student from the `Observable<Student[]>` based on their "bannedId", I tried:

```
students$.filter(student => student.id !== bannedId)
```

however I got the error that id is not a property of Student[]. If I supply an index i.e. `student[0].id` it recognizes the property but obviously won't do what I want. How would I go about filtering this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [`Observable.map(...)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)?

`students$.map(studentList => studentList.filter(student => student.id !== bannedId))`

It produces a new Observable on which you can expect the elements to not have student object with the banned id.

Comment: Yes I have to wait 8 more minutes before it lets me!